# PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

My code is for a script that looks at a folder and deletes images that are under a resolution of 1920x1080. The problem I am having is that when my code runs;

```
import os
from PIL import Image

while True:    
    img_dir = r"C:\Users\Harold\Google Drive\wallpapers"
    for filename in os.listdir(img_dir):
        filepath = os.path.join(img_dir, filename)
        im = Image.open(filepath)
        x, y = im.size
        totalsize = x*y
        if totalsize < 2073600:
            os.remove(filepath)
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harold\Desktop\imagefilter.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.remove(filepath)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\Harold\\Google Drive\\wallpapers\\Car - ABT Audi RS6-R [OS] [1600x1060].jpg'
```

Just to confirm, Python is the only program running on my computer. What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your process is the one that has the file open (via `im` still existing). You need to close it first before deleting it.

I don't know if PIL supports `with` contexts, but if it did:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

while True:    
    img_dir = r"C:\Users\Harold\Google Drive\wallpapers"
    for filename in os.listdir(img_dir):
        filepath = os.path.join(img_dir, filename)
        with Image.open(filepath) as im:
            x, y = im.size
        totalsize = x*y
        if totalsize < 2073600:
            os.remove(filepath)
```

This will make sure to delete `im` (and close the file) before you get to `os.remove`.

If it doesn't you might want to check out Pillow, since PIL development is pretty much dead.

Answer (score 18):

I was running into the same problem, but the error was intermittent.  If you are coding your file open/close correctly and still running into this error, make sure you are not synching the files with Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.  I paused Dropbox and I no longer see the error.

Answer (score 11):

This is basically permission error, you just need to close the file before removing it. After getting the image size info, close the image with

```
im.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases. For example, if I construct a path with the code `file_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"),'my_file.zip')` and then try`file_path.close()` I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, that's because you assigned file_path a 'str' object, not a 'file' object.  That's an obvious mistake to a seasoned Python programmer.  This answer is a perfectly acceptable way to close a file.  However, it is not as idiomatic as using the `with` context mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the issue, in windows [WinError 32]

Solved by changing:

```
try:
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    _, fname = tempfile.mkstemp()
    with open(fname, 'wb') as ff:
        ff.write(f.read())
    img = imread(fname)
    os.remove(fname)
    return img
```

into:

```
try:
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    fd, fname = tempfile.mkstemp()
    with open(fname, 'wb') as ff:
        ff.write(f.read())
    img = imread(fname)
    os.close(fd)
    os.remove(fname)
    return img
```

As found here: https://no.coredump.biz/questions/45042466/permissionerror-winerror-32-when-trying-to-delete-a-temporary-image

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will help.

```
import os

def close():

    try:
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe')

    except Exception:
        print("KU")

close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason the cause of this on my end was IntellIJ holding the handle of the file. Closing Intellij solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue and duh! moment with this one.

MacOS would accept *myfile.close* but I got the error referenced here when moving over to Windows.

Simply adding () fixed it on Windows and didn't bother the MacOS either way - *myfile.close()*