# Issue with removing files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently having some issues removing a file in python. I am creating a temporary file for pdf to image conversion. It is housed in a folder that holds a .ppm file and converts it to a .jpg file. It then deletes the temporary .ppm file. Here is the code:

```
    import pdf2image
    from PIL import Image
    import os

    images = pdf2image.convert_from_path('Path to pdf.pdf', output_folder='./folder name')
    file = ''
    for files in os.listdir('./folder name'):
        if files.endswith(".ppm"):
            file = files        
    path = os.path.join('folder name',file)
    im = Image.open(path)
    im.save("Path to image.jpg")
    im.close()
    os.remove(path)
```

The issue is at the end in the os.remove(path). I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'path to ppm file'
```

I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: resources are being  used , make sure you closed before removing

Answer (score -1):

Not really the answer to your question, but you can just output in the correct format at the start, and avoid the issue in the first place:

```
pdf2image.convert_from_path('Path to pdf.pdf', output_folder='./folder name', fmt='jpg')
```

To actually answer your question, I'm not sure why you're having the issue, because really the `close()` should prevent this problem. Perhaps check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27215504) and try using a `with` statement? Or maybe the permissions release is just delayed, I'm curious what throwing that `remove` in a loop for as long as it throws an exception would do.

**Edit**: To set the name, you'll want to do something like:

```
images = pdf2image.convert_from_path('Path to pdf.pdf', output_folder='./folder name', fmt='jpg')
for image in images:
    # Save the image
```

The [pdf2image documentation](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image) looks like it recommends using a temporary folder, like in this example, and then you can just `.save(...)` the PIL image:

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
     images_from_path = convert_from_path('/home/kankroc/example.pdf', output_folder=path)
     # Do something here
```

**Edit**: I realized that the reason it was in use is probably because you need to close() all the images in `images`. You should read up on the [pdf2image documentation](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image) and about the [PIL images](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) that it spits out for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the fmt tip, do you know if there is a way to control the name of the file that is made? Right now it is giving the file some random name.

Comment: I have tried your solution, not solving problem at all.