# Python `os.remove` gets permission denied error

Tags: python, opencv

I currently have a Python function that reads in image files and outputs the image, and then deletes the temporary files when I'm done using them with the `os.remove` function.

When I try to use the `os.remove` function, however, I get a permission denied error stating that the file is still in use. I've tried following what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215462/permissionerror-winerror-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is) suggests, but it hasn't quite worked (or I haven't implemented it correctly).

Here's the code in question:

```
def image_from_url(url):
    try:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        _, fname = tempfile.mkstemp()

        with open(fname, 'wb') as ff:
            ff.write(f.read())

        img = imread(fname)
        os.remove(fname)

        return img
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print('URL Error: ', e.reason, url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print('HTTP Error: ', e.code, url)
```

I've tried putting the `img = imread(fname)` line within the `with open` block but that hasn't worked.

Does anybody have an idea on what the problem may be? Thank you.

**EDIT**

More specifically, this function is being called by another script:

```
# Sample a minibatch and show the images and captions
batch_size = 3

captions, features, urls = coco_minibatch(data, batch_size=batch_size)
for i, (caption, url) in enumerate(zip(captions, urls)):
    plt.imshow(image_from_url(url))
    plt.axis('off')
    caption_str = decode_captions(caption, data['idx_to_word'])
    plt.title(caption_str)
    plt.show()
```

You can see that the `image_from_url` function is being called in the first line within the for loop.

The error traceback is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fe0df6739091> in <module>
      4 captions, features, urls = sample_coco_minibatch(data, batch_size=batch_size)
      5 for i, (caption, url) in enumerate(zip(captions, urls)):
----> 6     plt.imshow(image_from_url(url))
      7     plt.axis('off')
      8     caption_str = decode_captions(caption, data['idx_to_word'])

~\directory\image_utils.py in image_from_url(url)
     73 
     74         img = imread(fname)
---> 75         os.remove(fname)
     76 
     77         return img

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp_lg3agzf'
```

Comment: Without the traceback, no, we don't have any idea.

Comment: You should be using `tempfile.TemporaryFile` instead of `mkstemp()`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, I'll add in the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

```
_, fname = tempfile.mkstemp()
```

will **open** the newly created temporary file and return **the opened file** and the name as a tuple. The obvious wrong solution is to do

```
    temporary_file, fname = tempfile.mkstemp()

    with temporary_file as ff:
        ff.write(f.read())
        img = imread(fname)

    os.remove(fname)
```

The correct solution is to not use `mkstemp` but use `NamedTemporaryFile` instead:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as ff:
    ff.write(f.read())
    img = imread(ff.name)
```

And you do not need to worry about deletion.