# file does not exist when I want to move it

Tags: python, shutil

I'm preprocessing datas to apply deep learning on audio files. I have a directory of audio file (.wav) with differents length and my goal is to use 0 padding in order to have only 10 secondes files duration. I also want to move move files that are longer than 10 secondes in an other directory:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os
import  shutil

path_to_sound = r'my\path\to\sound'
path_to_export = r'my\path\to\export'
path_for_too_long  = r'my\path\to\other_directory'

pad_ms= 10000
file_names=os.listdir(path_to_sound)

print(file_names) # ['30368.wav', '41348.wav', '42900.wav', '42901.wav', '42902.wav']


for name in file_names:
    audio= AudioSegment.from_wav(os.path.join(path_to_sound, name))
     
    if pad_ms > len(audio):
        shutil.move(name,path_for_too_long )
    else:    
        silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=pad_ms-len(audio)+1)
    
        padded = audio + silence
        padded.export(os.path.join(path_to_export, name), format = 'wav')
```

When running this I got the following errors:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file can not be found : '41348.wav' -> 'C:\\Users\\path_for_too_long\\41348.wav'
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '41348.wav'
```

I think the error is due to the way i'm using `shutil.move()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shutil.move` expects the full path, here you are providing the `name` which corresponds to the filename and not the file path.

You have to update the line:

```py
shutil.move(name, path_for_too_long)
```

to:

```py
shutil.move(os.path.join(path_to_sound, name), path_for_too_long)
```

Remark: if you are using Python 3.4+ you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of os to handle paths. You can find 2 articles on this:

- [Why you should be using pathlib](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/)
- [No really, pathlib is great](https://treyhunner.com/2019/01/no-really-pathlib-is-great/)

Comment: Thx, it really help me

Comment: Some files are moving but I got the following error `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\path_to_sound"\\filename.wav'`, how am i supposed to close the file?

Comment: Hard to say what is the cause of this error, did you launch several runs at the same time?

Comment: No only python with Jupyter Notebook is running. According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215462/permissionerror-winerror-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is/27215504#27215504)   I think I understood that the probleme came from the opining of the file, but I have no idea how to apply this in my case

Answer (score 0):

before u delete,try to findout if is exist.

```
import os
path = ''
if os.path.exists(path):
    func_to_delete()
```

Comment: thx, but the error specify that the file does not exist in the destination directory, which is normal because he is empty and I want to move files in