# An error occurred while calling the "train_test_split" function

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

The following are the issues I have encountered, as shown in the pictures:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TcIP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu64P.png)
Help me!!! .I have spent the whole morning solving this problem, but it still hasn't been resolved.I can't find out the reason

This is a normal result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvdU4.png)

Comment: this happens when something is preventing that file from accessing. can you restart your jupyter notebook server and try again. check for any error while the dataset is initialized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError: \[WinError 32\] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215462/permissionerror-winerror-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is)